# Anyway to get the ID of processes created by Supervisord?

Tags: pid, supervisord, child-process

I need the process ID of processes created using supervisord for use in a script. Processes spawned by supervisord don't create .pid files in their default directories, if at all.

How do I get the process ID of a supervisord child process?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of supervisor version 3 you can use the `supervisorctl pid <name>` command to list `pid`s of managed processes:

```
supervisorctl pid programname
```

Use `supervisorctl pid all` to get a newline-separated list of `pid`s of all managed processes.

For older supervisord versions, you are stuck with `supervisord status`, but with a little `awk`, `sed` and `paste` massaging, you can extract those `pid`s to be acceptable as input to other commands:

```
echo `bin/supervisorctl status | grep RUNNING | awk -F' ' '{print $4}' | sed -e 's/,$//' | paste -sd' '`
```

would list all pids of running programs as a space-separated list. Replace `echo` with a `kill -HUP` command to send them all the `SIGHUP` signal, for example.

Comment: cheers Martijn. Irrelevant now thanks to your earlier answer :) Still cannot get group commands and restart working though.

Comment: Surprising that there's no straight forward way to do this. But this works like a charm

Answer (score 17):

You can now do the following:

```
sudo supervisorctl pid all
sudo supervisorctl pid myprogramname
```

Answer (score 0):

System centos7

command:

```
ps -ef|grep $(cat /tmp/supervisord.pid)|grep -v grep |grep -v supervisord|awk '{print $2}'
```

The file `/tmp/supervisord.pid` records the supervisord id.

You can get child process by `ps -ef|grep ${fatherProcess}`